# Are Folder IDs unique across Users on Outlook's Mail API?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-api

I want to be able to reference folderNames via folderIds in my data store. Will there be a situation where there are duplicate folderIds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FolderIds are unique within a given mailbox.

Comment: You know what?  I was thinking about some internal implementation details.  Yes, as exposed *outside* to REST and EWS, FolderIds are unique across mailboxes.  Sorry for the confusion.